# Why cant I invoke a function with paremeters multiple time in settimeout/setinterval

Tags: javascript

I am trying to invoke a function in my setinterval function like this

```
function dosomething(variable) {
 console.log(variable);
}

setinterval(dosomething(variable), 2000)
```

The above code only run once and throws an error after the second setinterval call?

I know I can get this to work using anonymous function, but why not this way?

Comment: Because `setInterval` (see the case as well) accepts a reference to a function, while you're passing `undefined`, since the `dosomething()` is immediately invoked.

Comment: any reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
setinterval(dosomething(variable), 2000)
```

is the same as

```
var x = dosomething(variable);
setinterval(x, 2000);
```

Using the debugger you will notice `x` is undefined

so you get

```
dosomething(variable);
setinterval(undefined, 2000);
```

Hence running once and straight away

Answer (score 3):

You can use a anonymous function which will call the `dosomething` method

```
setInterval(function(){dosomething(variable)}, 2000)
```

In your case you are calling `dosomething` and then is passing the value returned by it to the `setInterval()`